# Crystal Reports - Some fields not showing in Data Context

Tags: crystal-reports

***EDIT: I have found out that all of the fields not showing up in the field explorer are of a data type that is not varchar. The three that are not showing up are of type "money", "numeric", and "datetime2". I still don't know how to fix it, but I think this should probably help answer my question!***

I am working on a project with a database (SQL Server) I did not create so what I can do with it is limited. I made a view and selected the fields I needed, however when I use the Database Expert and select the view, only 3 of the 6 fields actually show up, and unfortunately, it's the 3 fields I need the least. I have tried adding a few different tables through the Database Expert and every single one I tested ended up with missing fields. I will say this database is pretty full of nulls and is badly designed, but since I created a view for this, I specifically excluded any row that had nulls in it just to see if that was the problem. It did not help at all unfortunately.

I have been googling this for about an hour now and I have found some people with similar issues but not quite the same, and so far none of the fixes have really helped at all. It seems like it should be something relatively simple, but I am very new to Crystal Reports.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT2: I have deleted all of the images as I don't want to get in any trouble for posting stuff from this project. I don't think there was anything in them important but safety first! Sorry if this causes any inconvenience to future readers :)

Comment: Have you verified that the data exists and is available as you would expect from the view/tables outside of CR? Also, the query that CR uses is available from 'Database'->'Show SQL Query' which could help you determine where you're going wrong.

Comment: @Ryan I have looked at the actual data in the view directly if that is what you mean. The table that my view is based upon has a lot of extra data and a lot of the fields are nulls. I made a view and cleaned it up by excluding null data as that was useless to me in this case anyway. One of the fields, for instance, holds the date a check was deposited. This field does not show up in CR, but definitely has data in it.

Comment: @Ryan I should also mention that when I go to the field context and right click on anything (the database, the selected view, or any of the fields inside the view), "Show SQL Query" is grayed out. Perhaps that is part of the issue?

Comment: To clarity, @zack, 3 of the six fields are not visible in "Database Fields" section of the report's Field Explorer?  If you `SELECT * FROM YOUR_VIEW`, do you get all of the columns?  Can you post the view's code (`CREATE VIEW ... AS SELECT ...`)?

Comment: @craig Whenever I select * I do get the proper results from the view. This is the View Definition I am using: 'SELECT stuff FROM table where stuff='value' and (column1 is not null) and (column2 is not null) and etc'

Answer (score 0):

If you use the single tables, do those fields show data?  If Xtal is not recognizing your types, you can always convert them to "better" types.

It would help to see your actual view definition -- your example is not specific enough and is confusing, indicating a single output column, and the logic shows testing for (and outputing) a single static value.  Seeing your actual table defs might also help.  There may be a much better way to design the report using the existing tables and the DB Expert (then again... maybe not, but how can we tell?)

Comment: [Perhaps these images will help.](http://imgur.com/a/mHcSn#2) It seems that it only likes varchar though that could just be a coincidence. Either way when I add the entire table instead of the view a lot of columns are still missing.

Comment: Images help greatly.  I added the SQL for your view in question.  A couple things come to mind:  1) If CR doesn't recognize a type, it guesses and does a conversion -- so I think you should be seeing SOMETHING.  If not, you can force an explicit conversion in your view.  2a) Are you using the same account for the (DBA) view creation/querying as for the reporting?  I have run into fun PERMISSIONS issues where tables and/or specific fields lose their permissions after db updates/table changes, etc.   2b)  A related issue could be DB security, with column-level access being limited internally.

Comment: Annnnd, one last thing:  You have the necessary permissions to create the view.  If you do a select * from MS SQL, I assume you see all fields.  If not, I'm wondering about permissions again.  Can you log in to the MS SQL using the CR access account and run the query/view?  If you see only the couple fields, then I'm back to permissions issues.  Hope all this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Marc. I have deleted all of the images as I have sort of solved this in a different way and do not want them to be there permanently just in case. I got around this whole thing by basically creating my own model so I could manually control everything. It isn't as easy as just adding a view to the CR, but overall it's probably better this way. I'm not really sure I should accept an answer for this as the exact issue wasn't resolved, I only bypassed it, but I do thank you for your help. This question can be closed out as I won't be checking it any more due to time.

Comment: OK Zack.  I prob shouldn't have posted the data w/out your OK anyway.  I still think we could have resolved it, but sometimes, it's easier to go around an obstacle rather than move it.

Answer (score 0):

I use dataclasses to create my reports.  When fields do not show in field explorer go to your dataclasses and change type of your fields that do not show to `nullable = false` or change type of data in your dataclasses only. I did it and it works.  I hope this helps you.  Sometimes you need to change them in your SQL table or view as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the dataset.xsd where you placed your datatables, select column of your need and change their data type from the properties.

Answer (score -2):

I did some testing and I found that it won't let me make a chart with a formula with a variable in it.

I can however reference a "variable evaluating" formula in another formula and that one shows up in the chart data view.

For example:

```
formula Blah
shared numbervar Myvariable:=10

formula ChartUse
{Blah}+1
```

Hope this helps somebody